# Alamofire + Combine publishDecodable to Future

Tags: swift, alamofire, combine

So, from what I could gather, on Alamofire with Combine we can now do this:

`AF.request(...).publishDecodable(type: DecodableType.self)`

which, if we want to map the error to a custom type other than AFError, means we'll end up with a method like this:

```swift
enum DifferentError: Error {
    case alamofire(wrapped: AFError)
    case malformedURL

func requestSomeStuff(url: String) -> AnyPublisher<DecodableType, DifferentError> {
    
    guard self.validateUrl(url) else {
        return Fail(error: DifferentError.malformedURL).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    return AF.request(...)
             .publishDecodable(type: DecodableType.self)
             .value()
             .mapError { DifferentError.alamofire(wrapped: $0) }
             .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

That `Fail` publisher doesn't seem right to me; Am I missing something here, or is this the correct way of doing it?

Should this be returning a `Future` instead and can that `publishDecodable` be mapped into a `Future`?

Comment: Why do you feel it needs to be a `Future`? `Future` is really just a wrapper publisher around some value that may come in the future via an async operation. Here, if `someKindOfValidation` is synchronous, then `Fail` just immediately returns a failure to downstream, instead of the AF publisher chain. Depends on what you want to achieve when you say "do error mapping"

Comment: Updated the question to clarify the "do error mapping" part.
Thought it should be a `Future` because it's supposed to either produce a value or fail, and it could fail with the `.fail(Error)` instead of a `Fail` publisher. 

This could totally be a non-issue though!

Comment: What is `.fail`? Do you mean `.failure(error)` promise of `Future`? It would actually achieve the same effect. The caller doesn't know or care what publisher this is - it is `AnyPublisher` as far as it's concerned, and both `Future` and `Fail` achieve the same result.

Comment: Yeah, I meant `.failure`, apologies. 
Well, if the method would return `Future<DecodableType, DifferentError>` the caller would know and care that this method would be able to publish only a single value.

To be clear, the intention here is not to turn that `Fail` into the `Future`'s promise `.failure(Error)`, but to make the whole method return a `Future` while still using the `publishDecodable` from Alamofire.

Comment: You can return a `Future`, sure - but currently - and generally from what I've seen - your API boundary is defined as `AnyPublisher`. In other words, the subscriber shouldn't care what publisher they subscribe to beyond its output and failure types. There's also a notion of demand, where a subscriber can demand only a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this at the Combine level (which you've gotten help with), I'd suggest moving your URL validation into Alamofire's request pipeline so that any errors go through Alamofire, rather than having a separate stream through Combine.
That way you can take advantage of Alamofire's features, like automatic retry, while simplifying your code. To that end, I'd suggest adopting either the `URLConvertible` or `URLRequestConvertible` protocols. These protocols give you an opportunity to produce errors when Alamofire converts the values into `URL`s or `URLRequest`s. For example, with a simple `ValidatedURL` type, you can put your validation inline:

```swift
struct ValidatedURL: URLConvertible {
    let url: URL

    func asURL() throws -> URL {
        guard validate(url) else { throw DifferentError.malformedURL }

        return url
    }
}
```